# How best to allow multiple categories for one user or id?

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I'm new to SQL but I'm trying to create a table for a directory type database. The idea is that there are companies (company table) that operate in one or many categories - e.g. bags, shoes, belts. I have a categories table just now with a list of around 55 categories - I want to leave it open to new categories being added down the line.

I've got the table laid our like this: ID, Company_ID, Category 1 (boolean), Category 2 (boolean), Category 3... and so on.

Am I along the right lines or is there a better way to do this?

The idea being the company will be able to log in, from this it will know their ID and they will be able to checkbox the selection of categories they operate under and save. Ideally I'd like to be able to have some PHP to display checkboxes in a form for this automatically rather than hardcode it. Later I'd then like to be able to select companies that have X category set as 1 from a search or a link.

Comment: Same as here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097387/looking-for-a-better-way-to-store-a-table-using-php-and-mysql/28097577#28097577

Answer (score 1):

It is a case of a many to many relationship.

You have to use a third table to represent the relationship, so you have the following three tables:

```
Company (id, name , ...)
Category (id, name, ...)
Company_Category (company_id, category_id)
```

Where `company_id` is a foreign key to `Company.id` and `category_id` is a foreign key to `Category.id`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The category table has almost 60 rows, will that work?

Just now it's showing as (id, company_id, art, audio, bags, barware, bedding,...,) or am I doing it wrong/too many rows?

Comment: I was looking to have set categories with a yes/no or active/inactive function rather than a list, don't know if that's the wrong approach?

Comment: Why do you have a company_id field in your category table? The right approach is to use a category table with fixed rows (you may add new rows as necessity arises) and then in the middle table add a tuple for each association Company - Category and then query this table. Otherwise, according to your approach, you need always to modify the structure of Company table every time you add a new category.

Comment: I'm envisaging a total or around 250 companies. And 50-60 categories. Each Company could have 1 category or (theoretically) all the categories, more likely to be 2 or 3 on average. I'm struggling to get my head around what should be included as columns for the category table. Just category id and category name or should there be a company ID (foreign key?) so I can associate categories to a specific company? Or is that what the joining table is for? 

And would it not be possible or ill-advised to include categories as separate columns in the company table and just have a flat database?

Comment: For the association you use the joining table. What you want to do is a kind of denormalization of the database. For these scenarios (if you really want to do this way) you might consider to use some NoSql databases and store lists in tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean... But, from what I've understood you simply have a n-n relationship between Company and Category, and you just need an intermediate table.
So, you'll have company, with its COMPANY_ID, category, with its CATEGORY_ID and the intermediate table, which can have its own ID, and two additional columns, one for CATEGORY_ID and the other for COMPANY_ID.

I don't know if i understood your problem, hope it helps.

Btw, this will be much better than modifying the schema for your company table every time a new category is defined. Please don't do that.

Comment: I think that's what I need... company 1 has goods applying to category A, B & C... company 2 has goods applying to category A, F, H... and so on. There can be many categories per company does this make a difference?